# What do i doing wrong on this UPDATE? MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

Following this syntax:

Here is generic SQL syntax of `UPDATE` command to modify data into MySQL table −

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1 = new-value1, field2 = new-value2 [WHERE Clause]
```

from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_update_query.htm

I made this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT, "UPDATE forum_topics SET player_userid = ".$player_userid.", titulo = ".$titulo.", msg = ".$msg.", data = ".$data." WHERE UserID=".$inTopic."");
mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT,$query);
```

But on line:

```
mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT,$query);
```

Is showing:

> mysqli_query(): Empty query in /var/www/html/ucp/php_func/edit_topic.php on line 30

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the query twice?  The second attempt is entirely invalid, but it's also entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Do you understand that you run `mysqli_query` __twice__?

Comment: Strings need to be quoted. `$query` would be a result object IF the query worked, but it failed. You are probably open to SQL injections as well, parameterize the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're trying to execute your query *twice*.  And the second attempt is invalid because, where it expects a string query, you're either passing it a result object or a boolean (if the first query failed).

Just execute your query *once*:

```
$query = mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT, "...");
```

Then the value in `$query` will be the result.

**Additionally**, you have the problem that your code is open to [SQL injection](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and you're not checking for errors.  If `mysqli_query()` returns `false` you'd need to examine what went wrong by using `mysqli_error($MYSQL_CONNECT)`, which returns the error as a string.

For the SQL injection problem, what you should be doing is treating values *as values* (query parameters) instead of as executable code (by concatenating them directly into the query).  [This is a great place to learn more about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)  Note that SQL injection **is not just a security concern** but is also a very common source of **errors and bugs**.  Since you're currently having exactly that problem, it's worth correcting.

Answer (score -1):

You should wrap your variables in single quotes, try:

```
$query = mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT, "UPDATE forum_topics SET player_userid = '".$player_userid."', titulo = '".$titulo."', msg = '".$msg."', data = '".$data."' WHERE UserID='".$inTopic."'");
```

Comment: True, but the error the OP is referring to is from `mysqli_query($MYSQL_CONNECT,$query);`.

Comment: Or use query parameters and avoid the problem (as well as other problems) altogether.  Putting SQL-injectable code in answers is rarely a good idea.  You also have *no* indication that this is even a problem with the existing code.  You're assuming a table schema that we haven't been given.